# Tensorflow object detection API not detecting all objects

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am attempting to use the tensorflow object detection API.  To check things out I have made use of a pretrained model, and attempted to run it on a image that I created.

But I see that the API does not detect all the objects in the image (though they are the same image of the dog).I used ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco pretrained model

I have attached the final output image with the detected objects. 
[Output image with the detected objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcIup.png)

Any pointers on why that might be happening? Where should I be start looking into to improve this?

Comment: Changing thresholds would make it detect a "dog" as a "cow" or "teddy bear".  I think what bugs me is its able to identify two of the dogs exactly with reasonable accuracy and does not detect the other three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-object-detection-example) comes with 5 pre-trained models each with a trade off on speed or accuracy. Single Shot Detectors (ssd) are designed for speed, not accuracy and why it's a preferred model for mobile devices or real-time video detection.

[image]

Running your image of 5 dogs through an R-FCN model `rfcn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017`, designed for greater accuracy over speed, it detects all 5 dogs. However, this model isn't designed for real-time detection as it'll struggle to push through a respectable fps at best.

Comment: Thanks.. This helps... I will gain a bit more understanding on the tradeoffs...I was able to get similar results as well..